# Creating indexes concurrently in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, parallel-processing

I found a procedure in pl/sql that creates indexes with **multiple threads**:

```
declare l_job number;
begin
    dbms_job.submit( l_job, 'execute immediate ''alter index idx1 rebuild'';' );
    commit;
    dbms_job.submit( l_job, 'execute immediate ''alter index idx2 rebuild'';' );
    commit;
end;
```

This procedure will be executed in parallel.

Can I write such procedure in MySQL?  Can MySQL execute a procedure in a separate thread?

Comment: You usually set up the database in a one off event. So why the need to be multithreaded? Just set up the database (create tables/accounts/indexes/stored procedures etc). Do a check on the SQL using EXPLAIN. Then things so be hunky dory. BTW - Forgot to mention that the limiting factor is IO.

Comment: @EdHeal The story is that I have a table with 300,000,000 records and I want to execute an update statement on it. I prefer to insert the records into a new table without indexes, and after inserting the records into the new table, add indexes to it. Now I want to add indexes to the new table with parallel threads. I got the idea from [link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330)

Comment: is this a one off event?

Comment: If i get you question right, Of course it can be executed sequentially, but I need to execute it in parallel.I read in [link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330) that building indexes for 1mln records sequentially took 76 seconds, while executing it in parallel took around 40 seconds.

Comment: If this is a one off event why worry over the amount of time to have a cup of coffee? And building a database is a one off event or otherwise something has gone astray.

Comment: which storage engine are you using? Innodb, MyISAM or other?

Comment: @Emyl My storage engine is Innodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you get 1 thread per client connection. To make this parallel, you would need to fire up a client instance for each index you wished to rebuild and run those clients in parallel. This link talks about the limitation at hand: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/27/mysql-limitations-part-4-one-thread-per-connection/