# Add some indexes to a MySQL table in parallel with Qt

Tags: mysql, multithreading, qt, indexing

I have a table which I want to insert some files into it and after that I will have 30,000,000 records. After inserting I will analyze the table repeatedly. So I added some indexes to my table to increase access time. But adding this indexes decreases inserting time and for 30 millions records it takes a long time. As the following links, at first I want to insert into my table without indexes and after that I want to add some indexes to the table in parallel (i.e. 8 threads).

[enter link description here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330) and
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107086/creating-indexes-concurrently-in-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

So I created a connection per thread, and executed each connection with a `CREATE INDEX` query in a separate thread but I see that indexes are added sequentially and since creating each index takes about 35 seconds so creating 8 indexes takes about 5 minutes (instead of 30 seconds). What is the problem?

This is my multi thread class:

indextodb.h

```
class IndexToDB : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QString connectionName_;
    QString str_;

public:
    IndexToDB();
    ~IndexToDB();
    void setParams(QString connectionName,QString str);

private slots:
    void run();
};
```

indextodb.cpp

```
IndexToDB::IndexToDB()
{

}

IndexToDB::~IndexToDB()
{

}

void IndexToDB::setParams(QString connectionName,QString str)
{
    connectionName_=connectionName;
    str_=str;

}

void IndexToDB::run()
{   
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL",this->connectionName_);
    db.setHostName("...");
    db.setDatabaseName("...");
    db.setUserName("...");
    db.setPassword("...");

    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare(this->str_);
    query.exec();
}
```

And I created the threads in `mainwindow.cpp` as follows:

```
IndexToDB ** itdb=new IndexToDB*[8];

itdb[0]=new IndexToDB();
itdb[0]->setParams("connection0","CREATE INDEX `index0` on tempTBL (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`);");
itdb[0]->start();

...

tdb[7]=new IndexToDB();
itdb[7]->setParams("connection7","CREATE INDEX `index7` on tempTBL (`col10`,`col12`);");
itdb[7]->start();
```

Comment: You may want to rethink your indexing strategy, sometimes it doesn't make sense to add an index as it isn't worth the extra cost to performance on insert or update.  If you have an 8 column table for example, you wouldn't want to create 8 indexes. Here is a slide deck from Percona on [MySQL Index Best Practices](https://www.slideshare.net/myxplain/mysql-indexing-best-practices-for-mysql)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  (There have been 2 significant changes recently.)  Please show us more specifics about the table and the existing and proposed indexes; there could be further tips.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a multi-threading problem, it's about table locks. [From MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index-concurrency.html);

> A CREATE INDEX or ALTER TABLE statement for an InnoDB table always waits for currently executing transactions that are accessing the table to commit or roll back.

So second thread will wait for first thread's transection.

You may consider of using InnoDB Fast Index Creation. [From MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html);

> It is possible to create multiple indexes on a table with one ALTER TABLE statement. This is relatively efficient, because the clustered index of the table needs to be scanned only once

Comment: thanks, as you said I can not use multi threads in indexing. I tested Fast Index Creation but I didn't see any parallel trend and it takes along as a serial indexing. should I set a variable or some thing like this to active Fast Index Creation?

Comment: No, documantation did not mention like that. But index creation takes long time naturally.